# Converting a tree to Binary index tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am reading about BIT(Binary Index Tree) which are useful when we have to do the following task on a array.

- change the value of i position of element
- Cumulative sum upto i element

As the time complexity will be O(logn) in second case , i am wondering what if  the above task is to perform on a simple tree , how i would covert a tree to Binary index tree.

For Example

```
                         1
                        / \
                       2   8
                    / / \   \
                   4  5  6   7
                            /  \
                           10   9
```

How can i convert this To BIT so that i can perform the above operation same as i perform in the case of array in O(log n) time

Comment: I dont know what the bit tree is but a simple segment tree will do. It is a standard datastructure. You can google it.

Comment: @piotrekg2 BIT is like a segment tree except it is more space efficient

Comment: What operations exactly do you want to perform on the original tree? Do you want to modify the value in one node and find sum on an arbitrary path efficiently?

Comment: @user2040251 yes same as we do in segment tree but i am wondering can we make BIT tree out of this

Comment: It is not clear what is a cumulative sum in an arbitrary tree. Could show a small example?

Comment: An excellent answer can be found here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10538/bit-what-is-the-intuition-behind-a-binary-indexed-tree-and-how-was-it-thought-a/10541#10541